# grep - how to output progress bar or status

Tags: bash, grep

Sometimes I'm `grep`-ing thousands of files and it'd be nice to see some kind of progress (bar or status).

I know this is not trivial because `grep` outputs the search results to **STDOUT** and my default workflow is that I output the results to a file and would like the progress bar/status to be output to **STDOUT** or **STDERR** .

Would this require modifying source code of `grep`?

Ideal command is:

`grep -e "STRING" --results="FILE.txt"`

and the progress:

```
[curr file being searched], number x/total number of files
```

written to **STDOUT** or **STDERR**

Comment: Have you considered using a script to do it? It's simpler than editing the grep source code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This wouldn't necessarily require modifying `grep`, although you could probably get a more accurate progress bar with such a modification.

If you are grepping "thousands of files" with a single invocation of grep, it is most likely that you are using the `-r` option to recursively a directory structure. In that case, it is not even clear that `grep` knows how many files it will examine, because I believe it starts examining files before it explores the entire directory structure. Exploring the directory structure first would probably increase the total scan time (and, indeed, there is always a cost to producing progress reports, which is why few traditional Unix utilities do this.)

In any case, a simple but slightly inaccurate progress bar could be obtained by constructing the complete list of files to be scanned and then feeding them to `grep` in batches of some size, maybe 100, or maybe based on the total size of the batch. Small batches would allow for more accurate progress reports but they would also increase overhead since they would require additional grep process start-up, and the process start-up time can be more than grepping a small file. The progress report would be updated for each batch of files, so you would want to choose a batch size that gave you regular updates without increasing overhead too much. Basing the batch size on the total size of the files (using, for example, `stat` to get the filesize) would make the progress report more exact but add an additional cost to process startup.

One advantage of this strategy is that you could also run two or more greps in parallel, which might speed the process up a bit.

---

In broad terms, a simple script (which just divides the files by count, not by size, and which doesn't attempt to parallelize).

```
# Requires bash 4 and Gnu grep
shopt -s globstar
files=(**)
total=${#files[@]}
for ((i=0; i<total; i+=100)); do
  echo $i/$total >>/dev/stderr
  grep -d skip -e "$pattern" "${files[@]:i:100}" >>results.txt
done
```

For simplicity, I use a globstar (`**`) to safely put all the files in an array. If your version of bash is too old, then you can do it by looping over the output of `find`, but that's not very efficient if you have lots of files. Unfortunately, there is no way that I know of to write a globstar expression which only matches files. (`**/` only matches directories.) Fortunately, GNU grep provides the `-d skip` option which silently skips directories. That means that the file count will be slightly inaccurate, since directories will be counted, but it probably doesn't make much difference.

You probably will want to make the progress report cleaner by using some console codes. The above is just to get you started.

The simplest way to divide that into different processes would be to just divide the list into X different segments and run X different for loops, each with a different starting point. However, they probably won't all finish at the same time so that is sub-optimal. A better solution is GNU parallel. You might do something like this:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
parallel --progress -L 100 -m -j 4 grep -e "$pattern" > results.txt
```

(Here `-L 100` specifies that up to 100 files should be given to each grep instance, and `-j 4` specifies four parallel processes. I just pulled those numbers out of the air; you'll probably want to adjust them.)

Comment: Very good and almost complete answer. Please post an example on how to use `find, parallel, grep` commands to accomplish the task and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @adrian: it would help to know how you are currently invoking grep: the `-r` thing was just a guess.

Comment: my usual grep command is `grep -e "STRING" * -r`. Doing a batch of <num_cores>*X files at a time is a perfect idea.

Comment: @Adrian: Ok, added some concrete examples, but you will still probably want to fiddle around with them. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try the parallel program

```
find * -name \*.[ch] | parallel -j5 --bar  '(grep grep-string {})' > output-file
```

Though I found this to be slower than a simple

```
find * -name \*.[ch] | xargs grep grep-string > output-file
```

Answer (score 1):

This command show the progress (speed and offset), but not the total amount. This could be manually estimated however.

```
dd if=/input/file bs=1c skip=<offset> | pv | grep -aob "<string>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you would need to alter the `grep` source code. And those changes would be huge.

Currently `grep` does not know how many lines a file as until it's finished parsing the whole file. For your requirement it would need to parse the file 2 times or a least determine the full line count any other way.

The first time it would determine the line count for the progress bar. The second time it would actually do the work an search for your pattern.

This would not only increase the runtime but violate one of the main UNIX philosophies.

> 1. Make each program do one thing well. To do a new job, build afresh rather than complicate old programs by adding new "features". ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy))

There might be other tools out there for your need, but afaik grep won't fit here.

Comment: OP doesn't say anything about line counts, only files. And it's not even clear that line counts would be useful; a simpler statistic to gather would be total bytes (which you can get from call to stat), and that would be a more accurate statistic as well, since grep actually reads in blocks, not lines. However, I agree with the basic philosophy of your answer.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the output 'number x' an thought he means line x in file y.

Answer (score 0):

I normaly use something like this:

```
grep | tee "FILE.txt" | cat -n | sed 's/^/match: /;s/$/     /' | tr '\n' '\r' 1>&2
```

It is not perfect, as it does only display the matches, and if they to long or differ to much in length there are errors, but it should provide you with the general idea.

Or a simple dots:

```
grep | tee "FILE.txt" | sed 's/.*//' | tr '\n' '.' 1>&2
```

Comment: How does this indicate status?

Comment: `grep -e "STRING" | tee "FILE.txt"` is hopefully the answer to your `grep -e "STRING" --results="FILE.txt"`, but it is not meant to be a full status like `x/total number of files`. It just shows the number of already processed matches.