# Grep - showing current directory/file in a recursive search

Tags: terminal, grep, file-search

### The problem

Sometimes, when I run the `grep` tool recursively it gets stuck in some big directories or in some big files, and I would like to see the directory or file name because perhaps I may realise I don't need to scan that specific directory/file the next time I use `grep` for a similar purpose, therefore excluding it with the corresponding `grep` options.

Is there a way to tell grep the current path directory/file which is being scanned in such searches?

### My attempts

I tried to search here but it's impossible to find something since usually the keywords `current directory` are used for other reasons, so there is a conflicting terminology.

I have also tried things like:

```
man grep | grep -i current
man grep | grep -i status
```

(and many others) without success so far.

EDIT: I have just found a useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684455/6854564) which is for a different problem, but I guess that it may work if I modify the following code by adding an `echo` command somewhere in the `for` loop, although I have also just realised it requires bash 4 and sadly I have bash 3.

```
# Requires bash 4 and Gnu grep
shopt -s globstar
files=(**)
total=${#files[@]}
for ((i=0; i<total; i+=100)); do
  echo $i/$total >>/dev/stderr
  grep -d skip -e "$pattern" "${files[@]:i:100}" >>results.txt
done
```

Comment: `find . -type f -exec echo grepping {} \; -exec time grep pattern {} \; 2>&1`  That gives you time to grep all files... not sure if what you want.

Comment: Just tried and I like it! I think you may consider adding it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find . -type f -exec echo grepping {} \; -exec time grep pattern {} \; 2>&1`

- `find . -type f` to find all the files recursively.
- `-exec echo grepping {}` to call out each file
- `-exec time grep ... {}` to report the time each grep takes
- `2>&1` to get `time`'s stderr onto stdout.

This doesn't report a total time per directory.   Doing that this way either requires more advanced find, to find leaf dirs for `grep -d`, or to add some cumulative time per path, which I'd do with `perl -p`... but that's nontrivial as well.